# como crear un menú desplegable utilizando addClass y removeClass?

Tags: jquery, html5, css

Verán estuve tratando de hacer uno,me dieron ejemplos aquí ,pero la forma en que funcionaban no la encuentro correcta.Lo que quiero decir,es que para volver a cerrar el menú hay que presionar el mismo lugar,o sino se utiliza la función   Toggle.me gustaria algun tipo de ejemplo usando removeClass y addClass y que este menú se pueda cerrar clicando en cualquier área de la pagina.No quiero animaciones.tampoco diseño sino la funcionalidad(JQuery).He encontrado ejemplos online hasta los de Boostrap son buenos,pero quiero entender el codigo y que no sea complejo.no quiero Boostrap. Ayuda, Please!!!!

```js
function showMenu(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#menu").slideToggle("fast");
}

function hideMenu(){
  $("#menu").fadeOut("fast");
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("li").click(function(){
    $("#menu").hide();
  });
});
```

```css
#menu{
  display: none;
}
.wrapper-menu{
  width: 210px;
  height: 310px;
}
#menu-content:before{
  position: absolute; 
  bottom: 100%; 
  content: ''; 
  height: 0px; 
  width: 0px; 
  border-width: 0 25px 20px 25px; 
  border-style: solid; 
  border-color: gray transparent;
  margin-left:0px; 
}
#menu-content{
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0.1em gray;
  z-index: 9999;
  margin: auto;
}
#menu-content li {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <a href="#" onclick="showMenu(event)" onblur="hideMenu(event)" >hola</a>
  <ul id="menu">
    <div class="wrapper-menu">
      <div id="menu-content">
        <li><a href="" >elem1</a></li>
         <li>elem2</li>
        <li>elem3</li>
        <li>elem4</li>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: En mi opinión estás usando mal el sitio. Creo que lo que buscas es una [_mentoría_](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mentor%C3%ADa) y Stackoverflow en español no funciona de esa manera. Te recomiendo que visites el  [__chat__](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=es.stackoverflow.com) de manera regular para este tipo de cuestiones. También te invito a que [edites tu pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) e incluyas un [ejemplo de tu código](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @toledano Porque mal?hace tiempo me ayudaron con eso,pero me di cuenta que tambien queria esa opcion.

Comment: 1. ¿Esperas que escriban el código por tí? No hay ningún ejemplo de lo que estás haciendo para resolver tu problema. Atención, no me refiero a que copies el código que tienes, sino que __muestres que estás haciendo para resolverlo__. 2. Dices que has encontrado ejemplos _online_, pero no los incluyes, por lo que corres el riesgo de que los repitan. __Se específico__, no pierdas tu tiempo, ni lo hagas perder a los demás. 3. Es mi opinión, por supuesto si alguien quiere y puede ayudarte, lo hará (aunque mi intención __también__ es ayudarte).

Comment: @toledano  Listo

Comment: Me pueden ayudar si o no?

Comment: Si, claro que puedo.

Comment: @toledano y entonces?

Comment: Listo! No había estado en mi computadora, solo hay que esperar las respuestas. **Aclaración**: Nuevamente, estás colocando el problema actual, pero no muestras que estás haciendo para resolverlo.

Comment: @toledano Ya encontre un ejemplo: http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_dropdown.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Buenas chicos,encontre un ejemplo en
```

http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_dropdown.asp

Así era que estaba buscando uno,pero no imagine que tenia que llevar un código Javascript como ese.